# Best way to iterate over an array without blocking the UI

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, backbone.js, settimeout

I am needing to iterate over some large arrays and store them in backbone collections from an API call. What is the best way to do this without making the loop cause the interface to become unresponsive?

The return of the ajax request also blocks as the data returned is so large. I figure that I could split it up and use setTimeout to make it run asynchronously in smaller chunks but is there an easier way to do this.

I thought a web worker would be good but it needs to alter some data structures saved on the UI thread. I have tried using this to do the ajax call but when it returns the data to the UI thread there is still a time when the interface is unresponsive.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I ended up using the example proposed by @jfriend00 with a few changes to incorporate different key values and a smaller chunk size due to a more expensive operation

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have a choice of with or without webWorkers:

### Without WebWorkers

For code that needs to interact with the DOM or with lots of other state in your app, you can't use a webWorker so the usual solution is to break your work into chunks do each chunk of work on a timer.  The break between chunks with the timer allows the browser engine to process other events that are going on and will not only allow user input to get processed, but also allow the screen to draw.

Usually, you can afford to process more than one on each timer which is both more efficient and faster than only doing one per timer.  This code gives the UI thread a chance to process any pending UI events between each chunk which will keep the UI active.

```
function processLargeArray(array) {
    // set this to whatever number of items you can process at once
    var chunk = 100;
    var index = 0;
    function doChunk() {
        var cnt = chunk;
        while (cnt-- && index < array.length) {
            // process array[index] here
            ++index;
        }
        if (index < array.length) {
            // set Timeout for async iteration
            setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
        }
    }    
    doChunk();    
}

processLargeArray(veryLargeArray);
```

Here's a working example of the concept - not this same function, but a different long running process that uses the same `setTimeout()` idea to test out a probability scenario with a lot of iterations: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9hCVq/

---

You can make the above into a more generic version that calls a callback function like `.forEach()` does like this:

```
// last two args are optional
function processLargeArrayAsync(array, fn, chunk, context) {
    context = context || window;
    chunk = chunk || 100;
    var index = 0;
    function doChunk() {
        var cnt = chunk;
        while (cnt-- && index < array.length) {
            // callback called with args (value, index, array)
            fn.call(context, array[index], index, array);
            ++index;
        }
        if (index < array.length) {
            // set Timeout for async iteration
            setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
        }
    }    
    doChunk();    
}

processLargeArrayAsync(veryLargeArray, myCallback, 100);
```

---

Rather than guessing how many to chunk at once, it's also possible to let elapsed time be the guide for each chunk and to let it process as many as it can in a given time interval.  This somewhat automatically guarantees browser responsiveness regardless of how CPU intensive the iteration is.  So, rather than passing in a chunk size, you can pass in a millisecond value (or just use an intelligent default):

```
// last two args are optional
function processLargeArrayAsync(array, fn, maxTimePerChunk, context) {
    context = context || window;
    maxTimePerChunk = maxTimePerChunk || 200;
    var index = 0;

    function now() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }

    function doChunk() {
        var startTime = now();
        while (index < array.length && (now() - startTime) <= maxTimePerChunk) {
            // callback called with args (value, index, array)
            fn.call(context, array[index], index, array);
            ++index;
        }
        if (index < array.length) {
            // set Timeout for async iteration
            setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
        }
    }    
    doChunk();    
}

processLargeArrayAsync(veryLargeArray, myCallback);
```

### With WebWorkers

If the code in your loop does not need to access the DOM, then it is possible to put all the time consuming code into a webWorker.  The webWorker will run independently from the main browser Javascript and then when its done, it can communicate back any results with a postMessage.

A webWorker requires separating out all the code that will run in the webWorker into a separate script file, but it can run to completion without any worry about blocking the processing of other events in the browser and without the worry about the "unresponsive script" prompt that may come up when doing a long running process on the main thread and without blocking event processing in the UI.

Comment: Added a more general purpose version that works via a `.forEach()` style callback so the same utility function can be used for many purposes.

Comment: Added another general purpose version that chunks by time instead of quantity so it will adapt its own chunk size based on how long the iteration takes (keeps the browser responsive).

Comment: How would this apply to `for..in` object enumeration? Create an array, then the above? (Or better ask a new question?)

Comment: @user - Yes, you'd have to create the array first (you could use `Object.keys()` to create the array) because you can't iterate this way directly with `for/in`.

Comment: Thank you. I though there might be some other nifty approach, but that should work.

Comment: I think using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` instead of a `setTimeout()` is a lot better. This way, you're absolutely sure your code is not blocking because the _browser itself_ tells you it's cool to do some processing.

Comment: @user1066231 - I'm not sure why one would be required.  It only calls `setTimeout()` after it has checked to see if there's more work to do so there wouldn't really be any reason to cancel that timer unless you wanted some way from outside the function to stop any further processing (which isn't a feature offered here).

Comment: Yes, my bad., I tried the last option with timeout , but the array obj becomes undefined inside the call back, which is called from within dochunk.

Comment: <Update> it was global variable , made it accessible and sorted out. Tnks @jfriend00

Comment: calling this function `async` is misleading I guess. The operations are still synchronous on the same thread.

Comment: You should wrap it with `Promise` to allow returning a value (`resolve`) after it has finished (all items traversed)

Answer (score 9):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c45Dn/) of doing this "async" loop. it "delays" iteration for 1ms and within that delay, it gives the UI a chance to do something.

```
function asyncLoop(arr, callback) {
    (function loop(i) {

        //do stuff here

        if (i < arr.Length) {                      //the condition
            setTimeout(function() {loop(++i)}, 1); //rerun when condition is true
        } else { 
            callback();                            //callback when the loop ends
        }
    }(0));                                         //start with 0
}

asyncLoop(yourArray, function() {
    //do after loop  
})​;

//anything down here runs while the loop runs
```

There are alternatives like [web workers](http://caniuse.com/#search=webworkers) and the [currently proposed setImmediate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setImmediate) which afaik, is [on IE](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/setImmediateSorting/Default.html), with a prefix.

Comment: Not as good as previous answer, because it call setTimeout after *every* element.

Comment: The 1ms delay isn't the reason the UI updates.  The `setTimeout` function will queue the function on the callback queue, which will get picked up after the UI has had a chance to do its thing.  You can just as easily pass in a 0 second delay.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jfriend00, here is a prototype version:

```
if (Array.prototype.forEachAsync == null) {
    Array.prototype.forEachAsync = function forEachAsync(fn, thisArg, maxTimePerChunk, callback) {
        let that = this;
        let args = Array.from(arguments);

        let lastArg = args.pop();

        if (lastArg instanceof Function) {
            callback = lastArg;
            lastArg = args.pop();
        } else {
            callback = function() {};
        }
        if (Number(lastArg) === lastArg) {
            maxTimePerChunk = lastArg;
            lastArg = args.pop();
        } else {
            maxTimePerChunk = 200;
        }
        if (args.length === 1) {
            thisArg = lastArg;
        } else {
            thisArg = that
        }

        let index = 0;

        function now() {
            return new Date().getTime();
        }

        function doChunk() {
            let startTime = now();
            while (index < that.length && (now() - startTime) <= maxTimePerChunk) {
                // callback called with args (value, index, array)
                fn.call(thisArg, that[index], index, that);
                ++index;
            }
            if (index < that.length) {
                // set Timeout for async iteration
                setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        }

        doChunk();
    }
}
```

Comment: rather than putting everything inside `if` I would prefer `if (...) return; ...`

Answer (score 0):

With the code below you can use either the function for arrays (to iterate arrays) or the function for maps (to iterate maps).

Also, there is now a parameter for a function called when a chunk is completed (helps if you need to update a loading message), as well as a parameter for a function called at the end of processing the loop (necessary for doing the next step after asynchronous operations complete)

```
//Iterate Array Asynchronously
//fn = the function to call while iterating over the array (for loop function call)
//chunkEndFn (optional, use undefined if not using) = the function to call when the chunk ends, used to update a loading message
//endFn (optional, use undefined if not using) = called at the end of the async execution
//last two args are optional
function iterateArrayAsync(array, fn, chunkEndFn, endFn, maxTimePerChunk, context) {
    context = context || window;
    maxTimePerChunk = maxTimePerChunk || 200;
    var index = 0;

    function now() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }

    function doChunk() {
        var startTime = now();
        while (index < array.length && (now() - startTime) <= maxTimePerChunk) {
            // callback called with args (value, index, array)
            fn.call(context,array[index], index, array);
            ++index;
        }
        if((now() - startTime) > maxTimePerChunk && chunkEndFn !== undefined){
            //callback called with args (index, length)
            chunkEndFn.call(context,index,array.length);
        }
        if (index < array.length) {
            // set Timeout for async iteration
            setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
        }
        else if(endFn !== undefined){
            endFn.call(context);
        }
    }    
    doChunk();    
}

//Usage
iterateArrayAsync(ourArray,function(value, index, array){
    //runs each iteration of the loop
},
function(index,length){
    //runs after every chunk completes, this is optional, use undefined if not using this
},
function(){
    //runs after completing the loop, this is optional, use undefined if not using this
    
});

//Iterate Map Asynchronously
//fn = the function to call while iterating over the map (for loop function call)
//chunkEndFn (optional, use undefined if not using) = the function to call when the chunk ends, used to update a loading message
//endFn (optional, use undefined if not using) = called at the end of the async execution
//last two args are optional
function iterateMapAsync(map, fn, chunkEndFn, endFn, maxTimePerChunk, context) {
    var array = Array.from(map.keys());
    context = context || window;
    maxTimePerChunk = maxTimePerChunk || 200;
    var index = 0;

    function now() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }

    function doChunk() {
        var startTime = now();
        while (index < array.length && (now() - startTime) <= maxTimePerChunk) {
            // callback called with args (value, key, map)
            fn.call(context,map.get(array[index]), array[index], map);
            ++index;
        }
        if((now() - startTime) > maxTimePerChunk && chunkEndFn !== undefined){
            //callback called with args (index, length)
            chunkEndFn.call(context,index,array.length);
        }
        if (index < array.length) {
            // set Timeout for async iteration
            setTimeout(doChunk, 1);
        }
        else if(endFn !== undefined){
            endFn.call(context);
        }
    }    
    doChunk();
}

//Usage
iterateMapAsync(ourMap,function(value, key, map){
    //runs each iteration of the loop
},
function(index,length){
    //runs after every chunk completes, this is optional, use undefined if not using this
},
function(){
    //runs after completing the loop, this is optional, use undefined if not using this
    
});
```

Comment: calling this function `async` is misleading I guess. The operations are still synchronous on the same thread.