# How do two things happen seemingly at once if Javascript is one-threaded?

Tags: javascript

Javascript is one-threaded, that means one thing happens at the time and there's a queue of events that get input and then executed, perhaps it looks like this:

`click > mouseMove > functionA > functionB`

But there's the confusion: does a function run stop for a few micro-seconds so that my `mouseMove` event is handled? How can I run a big function that takes a while to finish and still click items?

Assuming I was running on a very, very slow computer, in theory, would I have to wait for a `console.log` for my `mouseMove` to register and do its thing?

Comment: the code you write is executed in a "single threaded" manner ... however, there is a thing called an [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and most of the operations in, for instance xmlhttprequest don't run in this eventloop - they probably run in a separate execution thread totally unrelated to javascript

Comment: Events and timers are handled by the _event loop_. _“Assuming I was running on a very, very slow computer, in theory, would I have to wait for a `console.log` for my `mouseMove` to register and do its thing?”_ — probably depends on the JS engine. Some operations actually stop and let some events finish midway, e.g. [BigInt multiplication](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/objects/bigint.cc#520) (kinda… maybe only interrupt signals).

Comment: if your code is `while(true);` - in most browsers, (before they offer to kill such code) no events in your code will be processed until that loop is stopped

Comment: You don't need a very very slow computer to test-run your use-case just run the script `while(true) console.log(new Date())` on your `powerful computer` from your browser console and see what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid freezing the browser when doing long-running computations in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546493/how-to-avoid-freezing-the-browser-when-doing-long-running-computations-in-javasc)