# Titanium Event listener while long operations

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I am currently developing an app with Titanium framework. In a window, the application make an operation in a loop which may take several seconds to finish if there is a lot of data to get.

Problem is that the application is "frozen" until the calculations finished and I want the app to listen to event that can be fired during that moment. In most of cases, the loop finished in less than five seconds but there are some other cases that I want to handle, too.

Have you any solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chunk the work up. The answers here should help you get started.

[Best way to iterate over an array without blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344498/best-way-to-iterate-over-an-array-without-blocking-the-ui)

Comment: Thank you, this is the way I will use.

Answer (score 0):

The heavy task you performing on the main thread freezes the UI.

The only solution is to perform the task on another thread rather than main thread(perform on back ground thread).

But unfortunately there is no option to create a multi-threaded application using Titanium.

Check `setTimeout()` function. It can help you partially.