# Stop Running this Script Notification in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am having an issue related to "stop running this script a script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly" using IE 8.What exactly i am trying to do is loading large number of rows from database logic and binding it to the jqgrid on the client side.

Client Side Code-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var model = @Html.Raw( POSWebManager.MvcApplication.Serializer.Serialize( Model ) );

        var boolRenderer = function( row, column, value ) {
            var html = "<div style='overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: left; padding:4px 4px 2px 2px;";

            if( value === true ) {
                if( column == "Exported" ) {
                    html += "font-weight:bold;background-color:#99FF66;";
                } else if( column == "HasErrors" ) {
                    html += "font-weight:bold;background-color:#FF9999;";
                }
            }

            html += "'>";
            if( value === true ) {
                html += "Yes";
            } else {
                html += "No";
            }

            html += "</div>";
            return html;
        };

        var columns = [
  { name: "ID", text: 'ID', datafield: 'ID', width: 55 },
  { name: "TransactionItemID", text: 'Trans Item ID', datafield: 'TransactionItemID' },
  { name: "Exported", text: 'Exported', datafield: 'Exported', cellsrenderer: boolRenderer },
  { name: "HasErrors", text: 'Has Errors', datafield: "HasErrors", cellsrenderer: boolRenderer },
  { name: "FirstName", text: 'First Name', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 110, type: "string" },
  { name: "LastName", text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'LastName', width: 110, type: "string" },
  { name: "DOB", text: 'DOB', datafield: 'DOB', width: 90, type: "string" },
  { name: "IDNumber", text: 'ID Number', datafield: 'IDNumber', width: 110, type: "string" },
  { name: "StreetAddress", text: 'Street Address', datafield: 'StreetAddress', width: 150, type: "string" },
  { name: "City", text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 130, type: "string" },
  { name: "State", text: 'State', datafield: 'State', width: 70, type: "string" },
  { name: "Post", text: 'Post', datafield: 'PostalCode', width: 70, type: "string" },
  { name: "Email", text: 'Email', datafield: 'Email', width: 150, type: "string" },
  { name: "Created", text: 'Created', datafield: 'Created', width: 90, type: "string" },
  { name: "Updated", text: 'Updated', datafield: 'Updated', width: 90, type: "string" },
              { name: "ABN", text: 'ABN Number', datafield: 'ABN', width: 100, type: "string" },
     { name: "CompanyName", text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName', width: 100, type: "string" }
        ];

        var adapter= new $.jqx.dataAdapter( { localdata: model,  datatype: "json",  datafields: columns } );

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid( {
            width: 960,
            source:adapter,
            theme: getDemoTheme(),
            pageable: true,
            autoheight: true,
            sortable: true,
            altrows: true,
            enabletooltips: true,
            showfilterrow: true,
            filterable: true,
            columnsresize: true,
            selectable: true,
            pagesize: 25,
            pagesizeoptions: ['25', '50', '100', '1000'],
            selectionmode: 'multiplerowsextended',
            columns: columns

        } );
    } );
```

Can anyone tell me how to disable this notification

> Without using with registry or using ActiveX.
>   I am very new to jqgrid and jquery so please help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the long running or non-responsive script notification.  You can work-around it by changing your code.

The usual work-around to a long running process is to break the work into chunks that are short enough that they won't trigger the warning, then process one chunk of work, the do a `setTimeout(fn, 1)` to process the next chunk and so on until all chunks are done.  This requires keeping some simple state variables to guide each chunk.

The `setTimeout()` allows the browser to process any other pending events and prevents the long running script message.

In [this answer: Best way to iterate over an array without blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344498/best-way-to-iterate-over-an-array-without-blocking-the-ui/10344560#10344560), you will see a code example for how to process work in chunks like this.  There's even a working jsFiddle in that answer that illustrates the concept.

In your specific case, you could create a state variable for an index into the columns array and then process only a couple columns in each chunk of work, incrementing the index appropriately and when the `setTimeout()` fires, you process the next few columns and so on.

Comment: i am still not getting it how to do it, what should i put in do chunk method and how to initiate processLargeArray() method in a jqgrid method.Can you please guide me