# Rendering large set of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to render this with "Stop Scripting Dialog". Any solution can be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
document.write("<ul>");

for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){


    document.write("<li>");

    document.write("<div><input value='"+i+"'/></div>");

    document.write("</li>");


}

document.write("</ul>");
```

Comment: Do you really need 1 million list items?

Comment: 1. Do not use `document.write()`. 2. If you are still using it - write it once the string is built.

Comment: Yup.. Actually I need to create a nested tree list. the scenario is very complex. I am able to render 300 list items. but I need to render at least 100000 list item.

Comment: Consider using paging then.

Comment: What sort of page / website are you creating that needs so many elements?

Answer (score 5):

First off, I will assume this is a theoretical discussion because no page design should ever contemplate multiple millions of DOM elements.  If ever it was thought there could be this many elements, then a different design that involves showing smaller windows of the data at a time should be worked out.

To get around the unresponsive dialog, you have to break your javascript process into pieces and execute each piece separately while allowing the system to process other events between pieces.  This is normally done by breaking the work into chunks and then executing each chunk on a `setTimeout()`.  You can see several examples of processing a large array here:

[Best way to iterate over an array without blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344498/best-way-to-iterate-over-an-array-without-blocking-the-ui/10344560#10344560).

But, you have a number of issues with this test because you will also have to stop using `document.write()` because once you're letting the system processing other events between `setTimeout()` operations, you can no longer use `document.write()` to insert new elements in the parsing stream because the document will finish parsing.  Instead, you would have to change to dynamically insert the DOM elements at the appropriate place in the DOM.

Here's some code:

```
function insertElements(num) {
    var totalCntr = 0;
    var chunkSize = 1000;
    var parent = document.getElementById("container");
    var progress = document.getElementById("progressCntr");

    function doChunk() {
        var chunkCntr = 0;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        while (chunkCntr < chunkSize && totalCntr < num) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = "<div><input value='" + totalCntr + "'/></div>";
            fragment.appendChild(li);
            ++totalCntr;
            ++chunkCntr;
        }
        parent.appendChild(fragment);
        progress.innerHTML = totalCntr;
        if (totalCntr < num) {
            setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
        }
    }    
    // start the whole thing
    doChunk();
}

insertElements(100000);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/0vw82q5y/

This is currently set to 100,000 elements.  If you want to experiment with higher values, you are welcome to (subject to the memory limits of your system).

The system will be more responsive to user input while this is running if you decrease the `chunkSize` value.  The overall end-to-end time will probably get faster if you increase the `chunksize` value.

If each chunk could be it's own DOM tree such that it could be inserted in one single DOM operation, then the end-to-end time here would be faster. That is not possible if you're inserted all `<li>` elements though.  The use of a document fragment here tries to help with this issue, but in the end, it still has to insert each `<li>` into the document on it's own which really does slow down this operation.

Note: breaking the work into chunks may slow the overall end-to-end performance down.  I have not tried to optimize the performance of this code, but rather wanted to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 0):

When ever javascript updates a DOM object, the browser would have to render the page again; in your case it would be 1 million times. This is guranteed to slow down even the fastest machines.

Avoid that by generating the HTML as many time as you like, but only asking the browser to render it once.

```
var list;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    list += "<li><div><input value='" + i + "'/></div></li>";
}
document.write("<ul>"+list+"</ul>");
```

Comment: Do you mean list += instead of =? Also inserting one million elements at once will still break most machines.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, yes most machines will. i was replying to the general idea/method of adding new elements to DOM and that it should be done in one go rather than make the browser render the page multiple times.