# What is this.inc?

Tags: javascript, function

A function, such as below, may have a local function defining `this.inc`. <s>Changing the value `inc` to any other, such as say `i`, changes the result - so clearly, this `.inc` is not a user defined variable, but something else internal to `this`.</s> Is there any explanation as to what `inc` is, and why it functions like so?

```
function incr () {
  var i = 0;

  this.inc = function() {
    i++;
  }
}
```

This change in result can be observed in an answer to my previous question, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335811/1679669), such as in this construction (Thanks to Paul S for expanding it from a Ternary Operator):

```
if (total !== 0) {this.inc = (this.inc || 0) + 1;} else {this.inc = -1 +1;}
```

<s>So, to reiterate, changing `this.inc` to `this.i` (or any other variable presumably) does not work, but `this.inc` does work.</s> So, what exactly is `this.inc`?

---

Due to my tiredness and incorrectly testing `this.inc` before posting this question, I misunderstood the usage of the variable `inc` as being internal to `this`, rather than miscellaneously defined by the programmer, since changing it was not initially working for me. Due to this, this question is requested for deletion.

Comment: You're sort of right, but your wrong in that a ternary does not introduce any new function/scope/closure/context, which is why the behaviour is different. Rather than expanding out the RHS, and leaving it equal to the LHS, move the LHS into each branch of the RHS, then expand, and you should see how it works `if (total !== 0) {this.inc = (this.inc || 0) + 1;} else {this.inc = -1 +1;}`

Comment: @PaulS. Cheers, that works.

Comment: Although not a duplicate per se, `this` is explained answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485 (and linked questions)

Comment: @user2864740 It appears in my tiredness yesterday, my question was incorrect in that changing "this.inc" to another variable, say, "this.i" would not work - because now, it does work. Apparently, "inc" was not internal to "this" at all. I already understand the concepts you linked to, but am now unsure whether to request my question for deletion or not - but thank you for link nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this.inc is supposed to be used as a static variable. This means that the next time you call "progress()" function, the previous value of ".inc" must still remain. But I find this inappropriate. It's better to define "var inc" outside the progress() function such as the following:

```
var inc = 0;

function progress(total) {
  inc = (total !== 0? inc || 0: -1) + 1;
  var percentage = Math.floor(inc / total * 100);
  document.write('Processing ' + inc + '/' + total + ' ' + percentage + '%<br/>');
}
```

Technically, a javascript function is also an object. So within the function call, you can assign a property for the function using "this". So by declaring "this.inc" inside it, the function will now possess a property called "inc"

Comment: this is not a good solution, you can improve the original, but not like this

Comment: @KeithNicholas Is there any reason why this is so?

Comment: you've isolate the function from the dependent variable

Comment: @KeithNicholas Thanks, thought as much (didn't test it).

Comment: @KeithNicholas If you look at the "progress()" function in the link OP provided, progress() is obviously called only as a function and not declared as a new object. There's no reason to use "this" inside a function as this might confuse the programmer into thinking that the function is used as a constructor of a new object. Clearly OP got confused of the "this"

Comment: @RonaldBorla Yes, I was definitely confused although I understand it was a new 'instance' of the called iteration (so to speak). Your answer does also work in place of the original (even if it could be improved).

Comment: that is better, but the whole point is to not confuse beginners.. it's not hard to isolate your codes, but anyway, isolation is for a different topic

Comment: @RonaldBorla It appears in my tiredness yesterday, my question was incorrect in that changing "this.inc" to another variable, say, "this.i" would not work - because now, it does work. Following your comment made me realize this is no internal sorcery, but instead a failing of my tiredness and poor testing before posting my question. I already understand the concepts you spoke of in your answer however, and am unsure whether to request my question for deletion or not - but thank you for your explanation nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `inc` is a property of the function `incr`. Since everything in javascript is an object, any function can have it's own properties just like any other object. `this` is a special javascript reference which references the current object, and the dot operator is a way of referencing a property of the given object, in this case, the object's self.