# Load and process files in parallel with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I want to load *and* **process** files in parallel. My Problem is that the data processing in my subscription  isn't run asynchrously, only the http fetch. How can I also make the data processing in parallel?

```
await Promise.all(requestsArray.map((request) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post(request, new FormData()).subscribe(async json => {
          console.log('load data in parallel from API for ' + request);

          mylongprocessingfunction(json); // blocks further processing of other files

          resolve(json);

        }, error => {
          console.log(error)
          reject({ error: error });
        });

      });
    }));
```

Comment: What's in `mylongprocessingfunction(json)`?  What exactly is it doing?  Can you show us the code for that because the advice on appropriate techniques depends entirely upon what that is doing?

Comment: time consuming data processing of the json

Comment: I believe you're looking for web workers, though I've never knowingly used them

Comment: Is this code running in the browser or in nodejs?

Comment: If this is running in the browser, then this would be relevant [How to process large array with blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344498/best-way-to-iterate-over-an-array-without-blocking-the-ui/10344560#10344560) as it covers both chunking the work and using webWorkers.

Comment: it runs in the browser

Comment: Then, for actual parallel processing of CPU intensive work, you will have to offload the processing to a webWorker.  Only then can you get more than one CPU involved in the processing.

Comment: Or, get your server to do more of the processing for you so the data is already in an easy-to-consume state.